# Raphael SVG/vml z index with html elements

Tags: javascript, html, svg, raphael, vml

I have a html container with divs absolute positioned. These divs have click events that draw raphael svg/vml arrows between them - however if I make the raphael appear on the top of the html with z index I can no longer click the html divs, if I leave it behind the html I cannot see the arrows.

Is there anyway to display my arrows over the top of HTML but still be able to click the under lying html?

I have a feeling there is no way to do this and the best solution is to create my div elements in raphael. can anyone help?

I need the solution to work in all browsers including IE6 onwards

Comment: Your intuition is right, you'd need to recreate your `div`s into `rect`s in Raphael if you need IE6+ support. Otherwise you could put `svg {pointer-events: none}` in your CSS (supported by webkit and FF only).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, converting to  objects is the easiest solution, as @Duopixel suggests. I suppose you could make the s transparent as well and keep them on top.

This has the drawback of requiring you to insert linebreaks manually if the divs include multiline text. If that's the case, you might consider using multiple canvases. You could keep the divs as is, and insert more divs between them, each of which contains its own Raphael object for drawing arrowing between the boxes. While most Raphael examples involve a big rectangular canvas the width of the page, this isn't required.